# How I get data week wise from a calendar year according to calendar week in Java

Tags: java

I am not able to separate data dynamically week wise from a calendar year according to calendar week.
[image]

Suppose I have a calendar month of January-2019 and I want to separate data weekly, then we have 5 weeks for this month

```
1st week from 1-jan to 6-jan
2nd week from 7-jan to 13-jan
3rd week from  14-jan to 20-jan
4th week from 21-jan to 27-jan and 
5th week from 28-jan to 31 Jan and so on...
```

Can any body suggest anybody how I do that.

Comment: You need to show us what have you tried?

Comment: Assuming you want to display a month, you would start at day 1, while it's not a sunday, go back one day, display one week at a time until you've reach the end of the month

Comment: Standards weeks always have 7 days, so there is little Java will do for you regarding this nonstandard need. Just start on the 1st of the month, determine its length based on whether it's Monday, Tuesday etc, then for the following week it starts with a Monday and is 7 days long, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
    //create calendar with locale
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);

    //week of year you want
    int weekOfYear = 4;

    //set calendar to specified week of year
    cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, weekOfYear);

    //set calendar to first day of the week
    //(might be different in different locales)
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, cal.getFirstDayOfWeek());

    //print dates of this week
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE yyyy/MM/dd");
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        System.out.println(df.format(cal.getTime()));
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
```

It's set up for the 4th week of year (by setting `weekOfYear` to `4`) and prints the following:

```
Mon 2019/01/21
Tue 2019/01/22
Wed 2019/01/23
Thu 2019/01/24
Fri 2019/01/25
Sat 2019/01/26
Sun 2019/01/27
```

Is that what you need?

EDIT: Or even this (closer to your request):

```
    //create calendar with locale
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);

    //weeks of year you want
    int fromWeek = 1;
    int toWeek = 10;

    //date format
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE yyyy/MM/dd");

    //print date range
    for (int i = fromWeek; i <= toWeek; i++) {
        //set calendar to specified week of year
        cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, i);
        //set calendar to first day of the week
        //(might be different in different locales)
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, cal.getFirstDayOfWeek());

        //print date range of this week
        System.out.print(
            "Week no. " + i + " from " +
            df.format(cal.getTime()) + " to "
        );
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 6);
        System.out.println(df.format(cal.getTime()));
    }
```

It prints:

```
Week no. 1 from Mon 2018/12/31 to Sun 2019/01/06
Week no. 2 from Mon 2019/01/07 to Sun 2019/01/13
Week no. 3 from Mon 2019/01/14 to Sun 2019/01/20
Week no. 4 from Mon 2019/01/21 to Sun 2019/01/27
Week no. 5 from Mon 2019/01/28 to Sun 2019/02/03
Week no. 6 from Mon 2019/02/04 to Sun 2019/02/10
Week no. 7 from Mon 2019/02/11 to Sun 2019/02/17
Week no. 8 from Mon 2019/02/18 to Sun 2019/02/24
Week no. 9 from Mon 2019/02/25 to Sun 2019/03/03
Week no. 10 from Mon 2019/03/04 to Sun 2019/03/10
```